# gsub in r, only for some values

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am quite new in R, so I am sorry if this is too basic.
I have a ".txt" file with 586 rows that look like these:

data:

```
*M1,D1.13,o,o,o,o,o,-,o,o,o,-,
*M2,D1.13,o,ab,o,o,o,-,o,o,o,-,
```

but I need these:

```
*M1 D1.13 o,o,o,o,o,-,o,o,o,-,
*M2 D1.13 o,ab,o,o,o,-,o,o,o,-,
```

so, I used the gsub fuction:

```
gsub(",", " ", data)
```

but it changes all the rest of my data. How can I change only the two first "," of all my data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it worth noting **g** in `gsub` is for global, so one solution would be to call `sub` twice. @Avinash answer is better as it's one pass only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I change only the two first "," of all my data.

You may use sub,

```
sub("^([^,]*),([^,]*),", "\\1 \\2 ", x)
```

**Example:**

```
> x <- c("*M1,D1.13,o,o,o,o,o,-,o,o,o,-,", "*M2,D1.13,o,ab,o,o,o,-,o,o,o,-,")
> sub("^([^,]*),([^,]*),", "\\1 \\2 ", x)
[1] "*M1 D1.13 o,o,o,o,o,-,o,o,o,-,"  "*M2 D1.13 o,ab,o,o,o,-,o,o,o,-,"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3):

```
gsub("(?<=\\d),", " ", data)
```

You can simply use `lookbehind`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/76

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Small warning: it will replace any coma preceded by a number with a space, not only the first two (works on example data, but could give unexpected results on other data).

Comment: @vks yes I've updated the comment with "other data" instead of "real data" (I was thinking of future readers who may miss this point and bang their head searching why it does not work as expected :p)